# flask mail raise exception when there is error with authentication

Tags: python, email, flask-mail

First of all, I would like to thank everyone.

I have a quick question with flask mail.

I would like to have an exception or catch the error while sending an email.

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_mail import Mail, Message
import os, sys

app = Flask(__name__)

mail= Mail(app)
app.config['MAIL_SERVER']='smtp.gmail.com'
app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = 465
app.config['MAIL_DEBUG'] = True
app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = 'xyz@gmail.com'
app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = 'njhkjkjj'
app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS'] = False
app.config['MAIL_USE_SSL'] = True
mail = Mail(app)

@app.route('/email')
def get_email():
    if mail.connect() == None:
        print("Email setup/password is incorrect. Input your email creadentials in python app..")
    else:
        msg = Message('visitor blocked', sender = 'abc@gmail.com', recipients = ['xyz@gmail.com'])
        msg.body = "Hello, this is email test."
        mail.send(msg)
        print("Email setup is ready. Email is sent..")
```

I am trying to get an error and raise an error message with the above code of block where the password is incorrect. But it ends up with an exception.

```
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials o23sm485224lfr.302 - gsmtp')
```

Any help or suggestion on what can be improved would be helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Did you enable "Access to less secure applications" from your google account?
Go to your google account settings, Security > Access to less secure applications. You have to enable it.
It worked for me, your flask app should work then.